# Noob regex question -- Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I know that [abc] will match any one character from that set. The matched value could be 'b' in this case.

Is it possible to match none or all of those characters, in any order, using a relatively simple regex expression? So for instance, match either 'ab', 'cab', 'b', etc?

I'm working in Objective-C.

Comment: When asking regex questions, you should specify what language you're working in.

Comment: Edited question to denote language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[abc]` matches a single character that's either `a`, `b` or `c`.
What you want is to extend that pattern to more than one character:

```
[abc]*     -- match any number of a, b or c
[abc]+     -- match one or more a, b or c
[abc]{2,3} -- match two or three a, b or c
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: What if I want to match none or one of a, b, or c. So, each character should not be duplicated. 'cab', 'ba', 'ac', but not 'aab'?

Comment: @RyJ Actually, it's practically impossible with regular expressions since it requires computation, not just simple pattern matching.

Comment: That's okay, I can search for zero or more and then weed out the results that I don't want later. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: For completeness' sake: `^(?=[^a]*a?[^a]*$)(?=[^b]*b?[^b]*$)(?=[^c]*c?[^c]*$)[abc]*$` would match a string from 0 to 3 characters that contains a, b or c exactly zero or one times each. So it's possible with regular expressions, just hideous.

Comment: @Tim That's about as comprehensible as `a|b|c|ab|ba|ac|ca|bc|cb|abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba` and about equally scalable... ;-)

Comment: @deceze: Exactly. OK, I thought of another, general solution: `^(?!.*(.).*\1).*$` will match any string that contains each character at most once. But this is obviously very inefficient; probably O(N²).

Answer (score 2):

> So for instance, match either 'ab',
>   'cab', 'b', etc?

You can use the following regex for matching *atleast one* instance of a combination of a,b,c (as per the examples that you have given):

`[abc]+`

> Is it possible to match none or all of
>   those characters, in any order, using
>   a relatively simple regex expression?

If you need to match *none or any* instances of a combination of a,b,c, use:

`[abc]*`